# What am i doing wrong with this stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to teach myself react-native by building a new app, using Firebase as the backend. Currently I'm trying to get my head around react-navigation navigators to lay out the screens on my app before i add content.

The issue I'm having is that the stack navigator doesn't navigate. It renders the next screen, and adds it to the page, and then initiates the transition - but for whatever reason the transition just doesn't happen.
so the following events fire:
 * `willBlur (on the originating screen)
 *`onTransitionStart` (on the stack transition)

I've assumed i've done something wrong, so i've rewritten three or four times, and this final time i've boiled it down to the simplest possible iteration of the problem, just a stack navigator and two screens - and i'm getting the same issue.
I've gone through the documentation a few times, and i think at this point i've just been a massive idiot about this.

This is my entire app to show it

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class Main extends React.Component {

  navigateToList() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('list');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.navigateToList.bind(this)}
      >
        <Text>Go To Listing Page</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { refreshing } = this.props;
    return (
      <Text>LISTING PAGE</Text>
    );
  }
}

const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
  mode: { screen: Main },
  list: { screen: List }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'mode',
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainStack);

export default () => (
  <App />
);
```

and my package.json has the following:

```
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
```

At the moment this just sits showing the "main" screen, and doesn't navigate to the "list" screen. Also the button stops responding, so it looks like things start working but then never complete for some reason i can't explain.

Comment: It looks to work fine when I put that code in a snack: https://snack.expo.io/BJ5D0OfgB. As far as I can tell, your navigators are set up correctly

Comment: Some times react-navigation not working at reloading app, so uninstall the app and try again, it will work definitely.

Comment: Well this is running in the simulator through xcode, and when loaded directly onto my phone from xcode - and i'm getting the same results, even when i build a brand new project and copy this code into App.js, 

Although the fact this works flawlessly in Expo makes me think there's something wrong with my environment, I just have no idea how to fix it...